# How to fix Timeout error occured while waiting for acknowledgement using Arduino IDE 1.9.0 beta on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: arduino

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and have downloaded the Arduino IDE 1.9.0 beta from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software.

I added my user name to dialout group and rebooted:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

I launch it by :

```
bash arduino
```

then I compile a sketch for the board STM32F103C8T6. Sketch compiles fine.

But when I want to upload sketch to the board from a FTDI module I get this error:

```
Arduino : 1.9.0-beta (Linux), Board : "Generic STM32F1 series, Generic F103C8, STM32CubeProgrammer (Serial), Enabled (generic 'Serial'), None,     Low/Full Speed, Smallest (-Os default), Newlib Nano (default)"
Le croquis utilise 31540 octets (48%) de l'espace de stockage de programmes. Le maximum est de 65536 octets.
Les variables globales utilisent 1276 octets (6%) de mémoire dynamique, ce qui laisse 19204 octets pour les variables locales. Le maximum est de 20480 octets.
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
                        STM32CubeProgrammer v2.5.0                  
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
Serial Port ttyS0 is successfully opened.
Port configuration: parity = even, baudrate = 115200, data-bit = 8,
stop-bit = 1,0, flow-control = off
Timeout error occured while waiting for acknowledgement.
Timeout error occured while waiting for acknowledgement.
Error: Activating device: KO. Please, verify the boot mode configuration and check the serial port configuration. Reset your device then try again... 
Error: Activating device: KO. Please, verify the boot mode configuration and check the serial port configuration. Reset your device then try again...
```

I don't know what to do with this pass timeout error

Thanks

Comment: Which board are you using (not only the chip type)? Have you tried putting it into bootloader mode manually? Also, verify that the board is actually connected to /dev/ttyS0 - most of the time these use /dev/ttyACM0 instead.

Comment: it's a generic blue pill board. yes it's in bootloader mode and board is connected to serial port /dev/ttyS0. you can see the board here https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07CRHX5F5/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. Same setting witn Windows 10 works fine but on Ubuntu 20.04 i can't upload sketch

Comment: Well, with these noname boards it can be hit or miss. Does the eBook they send with it not contain any hints? And why are you using an FTDI module to program the board?

Comment: ebook explains how to use it with FTDI and flashloader on windows. I use this module because I already had one

Comment: Have you tried connecting it to USB directly and see if it connects? Maybe it has a USB  bootloader onboard. If not - well, then you know why it was so cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, in Arduino IDE go to Tools > Port
and choose (Serial Port USB) dev/ttyUSB0 not (Serial Port) dev/ttyS0